# How can you get a .net DataItem with RepeatColumns = 2 AND alternate row styling?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a list of objects which need to be output 2 items per row, and with each alternate row to have a different background (using different CSS classes).

Currently, I'm using a DataList, binding the list to it, RepeatColumns=2, RepeatDirection="horizontal". ItemStyle and AlternatingItemStyle are being used to style the two columns. This results in the right layout but I can't figure out how to apply a different styling per row.

I am open to using any other controls to get the job done. There must be a way to achieve this without writing out the HTML manually:

[alt text http://abunchofletters.co.uk/uploads/Downloads.png](http://abunchofletters.co.uk/uploads/Downloads.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is the repeater control.  Much more flexible, but the trade off is that you have to build the templates for it yourself.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

Comment: This is what I've ended up going for. Shame really, as the DataList was almost exactly what I needed.